# Go language, scanning embeded struct with sqlx.StructScan

Tags: database, go, struct, sqlx

I have just started learning Go language.
I wrote following simple program.

Here i am trying to fill struct with all Books and related Authers.

`Book` struct has embeded `Author` struct.

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

type Book struct {
    ID      int
    Title   string
    Year    int
    Bauther  Auther `db:"auther"`
}

type Auther struct {
    ID      int
    Name    string
    Dob     time.Time
}

func main() {
    db, err := sqlx.Open("postgres", "host=localhost user=testuser dbname=testdb password=testuser")
    if err != nil {
       log.Fatal("DB Conn error: ", err)
    }

    if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("DB Ping error: ", err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    rows, err := db.Queryx("Select b.*, a.name from books b left outer join authers a on a.ID=b.auther;")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("DB Query error: ", err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    var books []*Book
    for rows.Next() {
        var b = &Book{}
        err := rows.StructScan(b)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Scan error: ", err)
        }
        books = append(books, b)
    }

    // print all books
    for _, b := range books {
        fmt.Printf("%v", b)
    }
}
```

But when i run it, it is giving following error

```
[samtech@sam sqlxapp]$ go run main.go
2016/02/11 18:45:46 Scan error: missing destination name name
exit status 1
```

What i am doing wrong?

I have also tried changing field tag in `Book` struct to

```
Bauther  Auther `db:"auther,prefix=auth."`
```

and change query to

```
rows, err := db.Queryx("Select b.*, auth.name from books b left outer join authers auth on auth.ID=b.auther;")
```

But it doesn't make any change.

**EDIT**

After few try and errors, finally i make it working.

I have to slightly change the Models that i have created. I changed Book struct from

```
type Book struct {
    ID      int
    Title   string
    Year    int
    Bauther Auther
}
```

to

```
type Book struct {
    ID          int                  // Key
    Title       string
    Year        int
    AutherID    int `db:"auther"`   // FKey
    Auther 
}
```

Now, it is working fine. The mistake i was doing was, i added `Bauther` field as `Auther`. Sqlx could not understand it. But when i added `Auther` as anonymous embedded struct, the problem resolved.

But it introduces another problem :)

As ID field exist in `Book` as well as in `Auther` both the structs. Now ScanStruct is filling `Book.ID` with 0 in all rows.

Is there anything that i can do to avoid it?

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't seem possible with sqlx at the moment. There is a open issue for this: https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/issues/131

You can however do that easily without using sqlx:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

type Book struct {
    ID      int
    Title   string
    Year    int
    Bauther Auther
}

type Auther struct {
    ID   int
    Name string
    Dob  time.Time
}

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://localhost/testdb?sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("DB Conn error: ", err)
    }

    if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("DB Ping error: ", err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    rows, err := db.Query("Select b.id, b.title, b.year, a.id, a.name, a.dob from books b left outer join authers a on a.ID=b.auther;")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("DB Query error: ", err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    var books []*Book
    for rows.Next() {
        var b = &Book{}
        if err := rows.Scan(&b.ID, &b.Title, &b.Year, &b.Bauther.ID, &b.Bauther.Name, &b.Bauther.Dob); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        books = append(books, b)
    }

    // print all books
    for _, b := range books {
        fmt.Printf("%v", b)
    }
}
```

Basically you have to be explicit of your columns in your `SELECT` statement, so that you know the order of them. Then you create your struct and scan into each element with the same order as your columns in your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Ya, i can use Scan method, but in a large project where queries vary by just few columns, manually passing fileds to Scan will be cumbersome.