# How to map a JOIN onto an array of structs with a child array of structs

Tags: arrays, go, struct, sqlx

I have two tables in my database, `tags` and `record_tag`:

```
tags
----
id
name
```

and

```
record_tag
----------
id
record_id
tag_id
...
tag_owner (user_id)
```

I have these two structs:

```
type Tag struct {
    Id          int    `json:"id" db:"id"`
    Tag_owner   string `json:"tag_owner" db:"tag_owner"`
    Tag_id      int    `json:"tag_id" db:"tag_id"`
    Record_id   string `json:"record_id" db:"record_id"`
    Record_type string `json:"record_type" db:"record_type"`
    Record_kind string `json:"record_kind" db:"record_kind"`
    Text        string `json:"text" db:"name"`
    Meta        string `json:"meta" db:"meta"`
}

type TaggedRecord struct {
    Record_id string `json:"record_id" db:"record_id"`
    Tags      []Tag  `json:"tags" db:"tag_id"`
}
```

And currently, I have this loop that performs `n` [sqlx](http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/) calls:

```
taggedRecords := []TaggedRecord{}
for _, record := range body.Records {
    tags := []Tag{}
    _ = db.Select(&tags, "SELECT r.id,r.tag_owner,r.record_id,r.tag_id,r.record_type,r.meta,r.record_kind,t.name FROM record_tag r, tags t WHERE r.tag_owner = $1 AND r.record_id = $2 AND r.tag_id = t.id", body.User, record)
    taggedRecord := TaggedRecord{Record_id: record, Tags: tags}
    taggedRecords = append(taggedRecords, taggedRecord)
}
```

When I marshall `taggedRecords` into JSON, I get this desired output:

```
[
  {
    "record_id": "dfwref3f",
    "tags": []
  },
  {
    "record_id": "3lkgekrljdkjfkjekjkjker",
    "tags": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "tag_owner": "p0stman",
        "tag_id": 2,
        "record_id": "3lkgekrljdkjfkjekjkjker",
        "record_type": "candidate",
        "record_kind": "candidate",
        "text": "lol",
        "meta": "{\"name\": \"exxon mobile\"}"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "tag_owner": "p0stman",
        "tag_id": 3,
        "record_id": "3lkgekrljdkjfkjekjkjker",
        "record_type": "candidate",
        "record_kind": "candidate",
        "text": "df",
        "meta": "{\"name\": \"exxon mobile\"}"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Obviously, this is dummy data. The above implementation works, but I don't like this it because usually `n` will be 10, and that's 10 separate network calls to database. I've poked around a little and tried a few things.. I feel like it should be possible to make this a single query. I've tried implementing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35342337/6495654) solution, but it does not work for me since my root struct embeds an *array* of child structs, not just a single child struct.

I have tried this:

```
taggedRecords := []TaggedRecord{}
var s string
for _, record := range body.Records {
    s = s + "r.record_id = '" + record + "' OR "
}
s = s[:len(s)-4]

_ := db.Select(&taggedRecords, "SELECT r.id,r.tag_owner,r.record_id,r.tag_id,r.record_type,r.meta,r.record_kind,t.name,t.id FROM record_tag r, tags t WHERE r.tag_owner = $1 AND "+s+" AND r.tag_id = t.id", body.User)
```

`Select` spits out an error saying can't find destination name id, which is I assume because there are two id fields coming at it, it can't map joins onto two structs correctly (the `db` syntax does not seem to support dots to denote table names or nicknames), or a mix of both.

Is it possible / what is the best way to implement this SQL call and marshal into the above output format while reducing database calls?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IN expression to select a bunch of tags whole sale then
assign them to their respective owners in Go.

```
  WHERE some_id IN(1,2,3,4)
```

you can iterate through an array of ids to build it

Or you can avoid ambiguous queries by using SQL aliases

```
 SELECT t.id , r.id as r_id
```

And discriminates these columns in Go , in multiple ways( add a column to a struct, use sqlx struct tags ...)